# Access only second row of column names in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to read an excel file where the second line is a date in a string format and the first line is the weekday that corresponds to each date, and then change the second line from string to datetime. If I only read the second line as index, and completely skip the first line with the days, I do the following to convert it to a datetime:

```
Receipts_tbl.columns = pd.to_datetime(Receipts_tbl.columns)
```

How do I do that if I have a multiindexed dataframe, where the first line of the indices remains as weekdays, and I want the second to be converted to datetime?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give an example of what your data source looks like, so I'm inferring.

If you use `pd.read_excel` with `header=None`, it will treat the first two rows as data and you can manipulate them to achieve your goal. Here's a minimum example, with an example "real" data row beneath:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Mon', 'Tues'], ['10-02-1995', '11-23-1997'],
              [12, 32]])

#   0           1
#0  Mon         Tues
#1  10-02-1995  11-23-1997
#2  12          32
```

Next, convert the first row to datetime as you said in your question.

```
df.loc[1] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[1])
```

Create a multi-index from the first two rows, and set it as the dataframe's columns

```
df.columns = df.T.set_index([0,1]).index.set_names(['DOW', 'Date'])
```

Lastly, select from second row down, as the first two rows are now in the columns.

```
df = df.loc[2:].reset_index()

df
#DOW    Mon                 Tues
#Date   812592000000000000  880243200000000000
#0      12                  32
```

Note that DOW and Date are now a multilevel index for the columns, and the 'data' rows have been reindexed to start at 0.

Please let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this data in the clipboard

```
Day Date Data

Mo 2018-08-06 blah
Mo 2018-08-06 blah
Mo 2018-08-06 blah
Tu 2018-08-07 blah
```

Try

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard().set_index(['Day', 'Date'])
```

to get a multiindexed example
Then change the Date to Datetime

```
df2 = df.reset_index()
df2.Date = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date, yearfirst=True)
```

Afterwards you can set the multiindex again, if you want.

Note, check out the documentation on to_datetime if your
datetime string is formatted differently. It assumes
month first, unless you set dayfirst or yearfirst to True.